# May I ask why the texture in cycles is always dark, which is much different from the original color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, color

[image: The image on the left is the plane with a texture added, the image on the right is the reference image (original)]

**May I ask why the image appears darker when I apply it as a texture to a plane?** It's really different from the original texture. I want to make a phone screen but the image on the screen always gets dull. I use Blender version 3.0, Cycles.

Thank you.

Comment: The Nokia image on the left is the plane with a texture added, and the image on the right is the original.

Comment: I would recommend an emission shader, unless the phone screen is not emissive. Elsewise, that is basically how the image would look in a flat grey world.

Comment: Do you have any light on your scene?

Comment: I'll try it your way. Thank you very much